# Material UI Modal doesnt scroll outside of Modal Paper

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, material-ui

Iam using modal library from material ui and i want to be scrollable when the context goes outside of the visible eye. The problem is that when i have my cursor outside of the white paper, the window doesnt scroll. But when i put in the white area and scroll, then the content scrolls.

I cant find any solution to why is this happening and how to fix this. Is there any config i missing?
Thanks.

```
import Dialog from "@material-ui/core/Dialog";

const classes = {
  root: "modal",
  paper: "modal-paper",
  container: "modal-container",
};

const Modal = ({ open, children, onClose, className }) => (
  <Dialog
    open={open}
    onClose={onClose}
    classes={classes}
    className={className}
  >
    {children}
  </Dialog>
);
```

[image]

Comment: Kindly refer this https://material-ui.com/components/dialogs/#scrolling-long-content
official link from MUI Doc where you can find solution

Comment: There are both scenario either you want dialog paper scroll or whole body

Comment: @HarshadPrajapati The whole body scenario puts a scroll bar right next to the white paper and looks awful and it doesnt scroll either when you scroll outside the white area.